# DXA 1.6 cms upgrade script

Tags: dxa, content-manager, upgrade, installation, dxa-1.6

We are in the process of upgrading DXA 1.2 to DXA 1.6. In the CMS installation, I noticed that we have a CMS install and upgrade power shell scripts. We are using Tridion 2013 SP1.

I used the CMS upgrade script (`.\cms-upgrade.ps1`) to update my MASTER PUBLICATION with the schemas, templates and the core dependencies.

I noticed that installation script moved 'most' of the Developer and Site Manager roles from '**BB, Modules, Core**' to '**BB, Framework**'.

The rest of the schemas, templates and core dependencies were retained under '**BB, Modules, Core**' with no changes.

I still have to replace the Design and publish DXA settings and design.

For upper environments, can I prepare a content porter package of '**BB, Framework**' and remove the duplicates from '**BB, Modules, Core**'? I could NOT find relevant documentation regarding CMS Upgrade and hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although DXA supported upgrades since v1.1, the (simple) upgrade procedure was indeed not documented till DXA 1.7: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17

DXA 1.6 introduced a better separation of Framework and Core Module and as part of that, a `Framework` subtree was introduced in CM. The `cms-upgrade.ps1` script is used to re-organize the CM-side (before importing the DXA package), but you normally don't have to run it yourself; `cms-import.ps1` will invoke it if needed.

IMPORTANT: you must really run `cms-import.ps1` to upgrade; only running `cms-upgrade.ps1` is not sufficient!

Comment: Thanks Rick. I did an import and everything looks good for my master publication. I did not know the purpose of update and now I know :).

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  the DXA Framework is separated from basic but optional Views and View Models that were used in example implementation from DXA 1.6 onward. If you are installing it in CMS for your existing publication using the PowerShell script cms-import.ps1, then the script automatically detects the old folder structure and moves items to the new folder location for you (Building Blocks/Framework/).

So for higher environment you have to port items from Building Blocks/Framework/ as well.

There should not be any duplicates. But if it is still there then please remove it. Regarding the documentation Please check [this](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v6&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700)